# Java Mongo Aggregation Query

Tags: java, database, mongodb

I'm trying to count and save for each document the size of an array field. My code:

```
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("$pcount", new  BasicDBObject ("$size","$products"));

    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    al.add(query);
    AggregateIterable out = mini.aggregate(al);
    MongoCursor cursor = out.iterator();
    while(cursor.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(cursor.next());
    }
```

The error: Command failed with error 40324: 'Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$pcount'' on server

Comment: `BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("$pcount", new  BasicDBObject ("$size","$products"));` -> This is equivalent to -> `{$pcount:{$size:"$products"}}`  . Remove the `$` sign and check.

Comment: Is valid this sintax in java? Cause i'm getting errors